# How do I rewrite an existing file in a Java program?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that manages a Contact List document the user has. The program should prompt the user for the file they wish to import, then give them options to display the contact list, add a contact, remove a contact, and save the current version of the contact. Everything in my code works up until I try to output the file. I get a "FileNotFoundException (too many files in system)". Below is my code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class ContactList {

public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
{
    String contactFile = null;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter name of contact file: ");
    contactFile = input.next();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(contactFile)));
    TreeMap< String, String > contacts = new TreeMap< String, String >();
    Contact contact = new Contact();

    br.close();



    menu();
    int userChoice = input.nextInt();

    while (userChoice != 4)
    {
        if (userChoice == 1)
        {

            menu();
            userChoice = input.nextInt();
        }

        if (userChoice == 2)
        {
            System.out.print("Number of contacts to add: ");
            int numContacts = input.nextInt();

            for (int i = 0; i < numContacts; i++)
            {

                contact.setName(input.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Enter contact's name (Last name, First name): ");
                contact.setName(input.nextLine());
                contact.setPhoneNumber(input.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Enter contact's phone number (xxx-xxx-xxxx): ");
                contact.setPhoneNumber(input.nextLine());
                contact.setEmail(input.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Enter contact's email (ex. johndoe@gmail.com): ");
                contact.setEmail(input.nextLine());

                contacts.put(contact.getName(), contact.remainingInfo());
            }

            menu();
            userChoice = input.nextInt();
        }

        if (userChoice == 3)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter name of contact you wish to remove (Last name, First name): ");
            contacts.remove(input.nextLine());

            menu();
            userChoice = input.nextInt();
        }

    }

    if (userChoice == 4)
    {
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(contactFile);
        outFile.print(contacts.entrySet());
    }

}

public static void menu()
{
    System.out.println("1 Display Contact List");
    System.out.println("2 Add a Contact");
    System.out.println("3 Remove a Contact");
    System.out.println("4 Save Contact List and Exit");
    System.out.print("Command: ");
}
}
```

And the Contact class, if it's needed:

```
public class Contact {
private String name;
private String phoneNumber;
private String email;

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String remainingInfo()
{
    return phoneNumber + " " + email;
}

}
```

Is there a way to import a file, make changes, overwrite that file, and output/save it? I thought that outputting the edited file to the same location would overwrite it, but apparently not.

Update: The exact error message I get reads:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/jesbarba/Desktop/Contacts.txt (Too many open files in system)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:184)
at ContactList.main(ContactList.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

This is when using intelliJ

Comment: where's your code to output the file?

Comment: Is "FileNotFoundException (too many files in system)" the exact error message or are you translating it from a different language? If you are and this is linux/unix, can you run `LANG=C LC_ALL=C java ContactList` to get English messages?

Comment: @thatotherguy Updated question to reflect exact error message I receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to wrap your `BufferedReader br` and your `PrintWriter outFile` into a `try-with-resources statement` as next because otherwise you never close your files properly which can be an issue especially on Windows OS:

```
try (PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(contactFile)) {
     outFile.print(contacts.entrySet());
}
```

Comment: This worked the first time I ran the program, but now I can't run it with the same altered file. I get the same FileNotFoundException this tie saying "No such file or directory". I tried wrapping the BufferedReader br in a try statement.

Comment: You should restart your machine

Comment: Restarting did not help.

Comment: that's weird, I don't see anything else in your code that could cause this exception.

Comment: My bad, I did not read properly, you get FileNotFoundException because the file contactFile doesn't exist. You should create a File object first like this _File file = new File(contactFile);_ then test if _file.exists()_ returns _true_